# Как поэлементно перемножить окно на серию и получить сумму этих элементов в pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

У меня есть две серии: первая - это большой массив, вторая- коэффициенты. Я хотел, используя функцию rolling, поэлементно перемножить окно main_ser на серию coff_ser. Затем получить сумму этих элементов. Не могу решить вопрос с ошибка, делаю что-то не так

```
main_ser = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1000,2000,size=(10000, )))
coff_ser = pd.Series(np.random.randint(-100,100,size=(90, )))

window = coff_ser.shape[0]
main_ser.rolling(window, min_periods=window).apply(lambda x: x.mul(coff_ser)).sum()
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, **конкретную проблему или ошибку** и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. // Текст ошибки приводите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Нашел решение, только работает не очень быстро

```
window = coff_ser.shape[0]
main_ser.rolling(window, min_periods=window).apply(lambda x: np.multiply(x.to_numpy(), coff_ser.to_numpy()).sum())
```